# Google Image Charts - matching colors

Tags: google-visualization

I've been playing with this for the last couple of hours and it's doing my head in.

I finally got my line chart look right but for some reason the colors for the data aren't matching...

Now in my head I presume that the *chco* parameter matches the order of the *chd* parameter. But it doesn't.

Here's my parameters...

```
chxl=0:
    16th+Oct+2011
    23rd+Oct+2011
    30th+Oct+2011
    6th+Nov+2011
    chds=a
chxt=x,y
chs=620x400
cht=lc
chco=3366CC,DC3912,FF9900
chd=t:-1
    100,200,300,400
    -1
    400,300,200,100
    -1
    36,10,100,100
chdl=Total
    Adults
    Kids
```

Here's a picture of the chart. See how *Total* is blue on the right hand side but in the line graph it's showing up red. I don't get it.

[image]

Am I making sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove -1 from chd in all three instances.

[link](http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chxl=0%3a|16th+Oct+2011|23rd+Oct+2011|30th+Oct+2011|6th+Nov+2011&chds=a&chxt=x,y&chs=620x400&cht=lc&chco=3366CC,DC3912,FF9900&chd=t:100,200,300,400|400,300,200,100|36,10,100,100&chdl=Total|Adults|Kids)

Comment: Wow. It was that simple... Thanks so much for your help! I'm such a noob!